# Is there a way to stream the output of a long Groovy execute() command to the console rather than wait for it to finish?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm running a shell command via a system Groovy script. It's a long running process, about 30 minutes, and it is quite verbose. But as written, this waits for the command to complete before printing stdout or stderr. Is there a way to have the output go to the console as the script executes (like it would in a terminal session).

```
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
def proc = "/some/long/running/command".execute()

proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
println "STDOUT\n $sout"
println "STDERR\n $serr"
```

Update: This is the code I'm trying based on the answer. It doesn't print anything until after the process completes, or is killed.

```
def cmd = "/home/adam/test.sh"
StringBuffer sout = new StringBuffer()
StringBuffer serr = new StringBuffer()
def process = cmd.execute()
process.waitForProcessOutput sout, serr
sout.each 
   println "Line ${it}"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the solution I found.

```
proc.in.eachLine { line -> println line }
proc.out.close()
proc.waitFor()
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 7):

While the solution you found will probably work fine, I think it is better to use [`waitForProcessOutput`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ProcessGroovyMethods.html#waitForProcessOutput-java.lang.Process-java.io.OutputStream-java.io.OutputStream-) which also allows to stream the error output of the process.

The full solution would be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
Process proc = "ping -c 10 google.com".execute()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
System.exit(proc.exitValue())
```

There are several alternatives to this method to capture only normal output or only error output for example. You can find them [here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ProcessGroovyMethods.html).

There is also a (rather short) chapter on executing external processes on the [Groovy docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#process-management).

Comment: Doesn't waitForProcessOutput() wait until the process has completed before the output is available?

Comment: No, it outputs immediately but blocks until the process is finished. So you will always get the full output.

Comment: I guess the part I'm missing then, is how to print the output which the process is running. Given the following code, it doesn't print anything until I kill the "test.sh" script, which is just and endless loop print the date, and sleeping for 30 seconds.   def cmd = 
   "/home/adam/test.sh"
   StringBuffer sout = new StringBuffer()
   StringBuffer serr = new StringBuffer()
   def process = cmd.execute()
   process.waitForProcessOutput sout, serr
   sout.each {
       println "Line ${it}"
   }

Comment: I changed the code. There might have been an error in the previous one. I tried the new one myself. It outputs every line `ping` returns and terminates after the process terminates.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the statement or statements you're using to print the stream?

Comment: I did. What the code does is, it linkes the output of the process to the system output. So whatever output the process produces is directed to stdout und stderr.

Comment: I see, thanks for all of the responses Michael. I'm running this as an "execute system Groovy script" and it doesn't output anything. Strange, I would have expected it to go to the Console Output during the build.

Comment: I updated the example to be a fully functioning Groovy script. As I said, it works just fine for me.

Comment: I think the reason our tests don't have the same results is that I'm using an "execute system Groovy script" build step, which uses the internal Groovy engine, you're calling Groovy externally like a shell script build step.

Comment: Oh, I did not realize your question is about Jenkins. Why don't you use `sh`? AFAIK this will do exactly what you want. See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#-sh-%20shell%20script

Comment: Yeah, sorry I wasn't more clear on that. And the reason I was using a system Groovy script build step vs. a pipeline was because I can then easily do post-build steps, whereas with a pipeline I have to code them. In any case, I've gotten better at coding post steps in pipelines, and I'm going to do it that way. Thanks again :)

Comment: getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress` when executing a docker container

Answer (score 3):

After a long search, I was not able to get the exact solution. This worked for me:

```
public int Execute(def command, File dir) {
          println("command: ${command}")
          Process process = command.execute(null, dir)
          def out = new StringBuffer()
          def err = new StringBuffer()
          process.consumeProcessOutput(out, err)
          while(1) {
              err.eachLine {line, count ->
                  println("${line}")
                  err.setLength(0)
              }
              out.eachLine { line, count ->
                  println("${line}")
                  out.setLength(0)
              }
              if(! process.isAlive()) {
                  break
                  }
              }
         return process.exitValue()
         }
```

Comment: This... needs to run the `eachLine` instead a thread, and then have the main thread call something like process.waitFor().... otherwise, you might block to read stderr that returns nothing, and never see stdout.

Answer (score 1):

The below script works :

```
    def pmdCommand = "java -cp D:\\Users\\user1\\work\\backup\\work\\LOG-SHELL-FIX\\EAR\\Encrypter.jar com.mdm.custom.main.Encrypter password123 ${publicKey}"
    def sout = new StringBuffer()
    def serr = new StringBuffer()

    Process process = pmdCommand.execute()
    process.waitForProcessOutput(sout,serr) // This is a better way to read the output
    if(sout.size()>0) log.info "$sout"
    if(serr.size()>0) log.info "$serr"
```

The Groovy method reference is available at : http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ProcessGroovyMethods.html